# AEM - grid container visible in editor/preview but not when published

Tags: adobe, aem

Running AEM 6.5.8.0 and we've a range of content in grid containers that no longer render visibly despite the code being present when viewing source.

For instance, on https://www.redfcu.org content below "featured rates" can be seen, edited in author, and the source is present when published, but does not render in the browser.  Our implementation partner has not responded to the issue in several days, and Adobe's only solution is restore from back-up, but without knowing the root cause, I'm hesitant to just restore for the sake of it.

[content in author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIrdG.png)

[content when published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBzDE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see the content now, and I guess the issue has been solved. What was the root cause. In the future, if you have access to the logs, there should be errors or warnings printed in `error.log` (or in the default project log `project-name-project.log`) when you try to access that page. Missing content in publish is a common issue. In this case, it could be that this component is reading the child pages below a given path and these pages or experience fragments are not present in the publish instance. Similar scenarios happen when the content is tagged but the tags are not published, or there is a failure in a logic validating if you are on author/publish mode.